# Is it possible to slow down the preview rendering?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I would like to have a large preview window that updates slowly.

The blender UI becomes near unresponsive with a large preview running.

Is it possible to somehow rate limit the speed of the gpu?

I have a 4k display. On a 1080p display its easy to use a small preview, but on my screen I need a larger preview window to work.

Comment: In Render->Performance->start resolution you can set it to lower values, it will not slow down but starts at lower resolution

Comment: I'm sorry, but is it that you are trying to do? If you're trying to get a faster (real-time) animation, then you should probably be avoiding the Render-Preview mode. If you want to know what it looks like when rendered, I would render a sample image. Yes, render preview mode can take up a lot of resources, but what are you trying to use it for?

Comment: It seems like the UI updates once per sample. I don't think slowing down the rate at which samples are computed will really help this, it will just make the UI responsive for an extra second between samples before it freezes again. A better solution might be something like tiled rendering, which would allow the samples to be computed much faster (letting the GPU get back to drawing the UI more often)

Comment: I want to have a live preview while I make changes. But when making the preview large, it lags out the entire UI. I would like to allocate less resources to that window so I can still see how it looks when I glance over, but not lag out my system.

Comment: Seems to me you have reached the limits of your hardware. Try rendering only the areas you want to affect by setting border rendering (ctrl b)

Comment: @cegaton That is the point of this question. I want to keep a large render preview area, but have it update slower without bogging me down. I already set the render border, but I still need to have a tiny preview window.

Comment: I hate to say this, but the Render Preview mode doesn't give you the same results as actually rendering. At-least, it doesn't give me the same results on my machine. It gives me something that's close to what I'm going to get, but it doesn't give me the exact thing I'm going to render. For instance, I might have a light hidden to allow Render-Preview to work faster, this can have a big effect on what I'll see.